# RenderScript: Assertion failed in rsObjectBase.cpp

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I saw a lot of the following error messages in the logcat output of my app:

```
E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: mSysRefCount > 0, in frameworks/rs/rsObjectBase.cpp at 147
```

Despite of this the app did mostly work but sometimes it would crash with SIGSEGV after starting the RenderScript code for a couple of times.

I was able to track down the problem (well, I think). I had a function in my renderscript code that returned an `rs_allocation` and was defined and used somewhat like this:

```
rs_allocation gTmp1;
rs_allocation gTmp2;

static rs_allocation blur(float size) {
    if (some_criterion())
        return gTmp1;
    else
        return gTmp2;
}

...
rs_allocation tmp = blur(size);
```

After changing the function definition to the following the error message went away and the app has not crashed since:

```
static bool blur(float size) {
    if (some_criterion())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

...
bool blurred = blur(size);
rs_allocation tmp = blurred ? gTmp2 : gTmp1;
```

Now the question is, why does this make any difference? After all `rs_allocation` is defined just as an `int` pointer in [rs_types.rsh](https://developer.android.com/reference/renderscript/rs__types_8rsh_source.html). So nothing too fancy should be happening when a function returns an `rs_allocation`, right?

Comment: Seems that something is wrong with the ref-counting for global rs objects. Could you share the build setup and the devices you were using when the error happened?

Comment: @MiaoWang, my primary test device is a Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1. I've also got a crash report from an LG G4 (p1), Android 6.0, in the Developer Console. Build setup is targetSdkVersion 18, not using the support library, anything else you need?

Comment: Last line of SIGSEGV backtrace is "#02 pc 00000594 /data/data/com.my.app/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cachelibrs.digit_normalize#SW0fAC.so (deleted)". The "deleted" part might be interesting. Let me know if you need more.